# How take this json path in newtonsoft.json C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, jsonpath

I have been building an application where JSON will be provided from a user API.  It should read the data from the JSON using JSONPath and persist the selected portions. I am trying to do this using `Json.Net` (Newtonsoft).  The following JSON is a sample:

```
{
  // other properties here and different structure here

  "Data": [
    {
      "Code": "625087",
      "Name": "Customer Name",
      "Email": "test@hfgidfgd.com"
    },
    {
      "Code": "625087",
      "Name": "Customer Name",
      "Email": "test@hfgidfgd.com"
    },
    {
      "Code": "625087",
      "Name": "Customer Name",
      "Email": "test@hfgidfgd.com"
    }
  ],

  // other properties here and different structure here
}
```

I would like to extract the array presented by the `Data` property content using JSONPath and convert it to `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` to manipulate in my application.

In tools like [jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com) the following JSONPath query works fine but with Newtonsoft it does not:

```
// get that json
string content = GetJson();

var jo = JObject.Parse(content);

var jsonPath = "$..Data.*";
var jsonPathResult = jo.SelectTokens(jsonPath, true /* to get error when it is not found */ );
```

Instead I got the exception:

> Property '*' not valid on JArray.

If I do the JSONPath like this:

```
var jsonPath = "$..Data"; // same for just: "Data"
var jsonPathResult = jo.SelectTokens(jsonPath);
```

I have to loop on the result with two nested foreach, what I think it is not an elegant solution:

```
var result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var jsonResult in jsonPathResult)
{
    foreach (var item in jsonResult)
    {
        var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(item.ToString());

        // some adjusts on the fields dictionary will be applied here...

        result.Add(fields);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the result to take a single loop the only the content of `Data` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [*JSONPath - XPath for JSON*](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), the syntax for an array element wildcard is `[*]`.  Thus your code should look like:

```
var jsonPath = "$..Data[*]";
var result = jo.SelectTokens(jsonPath, true /* to get error when it is not found */ )
    .Select(o => o.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>())
    .ToList();
```

Here I am using [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) to deserialize each array element directly to a `Dictionary<string, object>>` without re-serializing to a string.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tr0uQG).